# Change sheet name inside formula by changing cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have this formula:

```
=COUNTIF('5-5-2014'!H:H;"NEW")
```

and I have cell K9 have a value of "5-5-2014".
I want to modify this formula so that I could change sheet name inside formula by changing cell K9 Value. So I want something like this:

```
=COUNTIF('K9'!H:H;"NEW")
```

I know this formula is totally wrong! Is there any way doing that?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&K9&"'!H:H"),"NEW")`
Where K9 contains the sheet name